# Request Error: Invalid Uri with vue cli devserver proxy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, jira-rest-api, vue-cli

I want to switch from Vue CDN to Vue CLI.

Before, I was using the jiraClient module to fetch information with the API.

```
var jiraClient = require('jira-client')
```

To turn off CORS issues, I simply added the flag mode inside the options like this:

```
methods: {
    getLogin: function() {
        this.options = {
          host: '[my company shortcut]-tomcat-jira.[my company name].org/jira',
          apiVersion: 'latest',
          username: this.uname,
          password: this.pword,
          mode: 'cors',
        }
[...]

this.jira = new jiraClient(this.options)
```

Now with the Vue CLI, I updated that code with a proxy host

```
methods: {
    getLogin: function() {
        this.options = {
          host: 'http://localhost:8080',
          apiVersion: 'latest',
          username: this.uname,
          password: this.pword,
          mode: 'cors',
        }
```

But since I added the Vue CLI, I have CORS issues again. So I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsYrDu7xkEw&feature=youtu.be).

Now I don't have CORS issues. I added `vue.config.js` file and added this code in it:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer:{
        proxy: 'http://[my company shortcut]-tomcat-jira.[my Company name].org/jira'
    }
  };
```

The error is

> RequestError {name: "RequestError", message: "Error: Invalid URI
>   "`http:///[http//localhost:8080]`...

It seems like the proxy doesn't work as intended. The options in the jiraClient object are not updated with the proxy URL. Am I missing a step?

**EDIT**: as mention in the comment, I removed the "http://" and added a port option. Now the error changed to 404 `Connection error: StatusCodeError: 404 - "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET ^...¸`

Comment: Have you tried `host: 'localhost:8080'`, dropping the `http://`?

Comment: Or perhaps `host: 'localhost', port: 8080`? That seems to be what the code's expecting: https://github.com/jira-node/node-jira-client/blob/b08dbafcba709427c0be87fc3be796e549d29867/src/jira.js#L148

Comment: I removed the `http://` but got this error `Failed to parse URL from //[localhost:8080]:80/rest/api/`

Comment: With `host: 'localhost', port: 8080` I have now a 404 error